# How to create vb app as a Microsoft Word right-click menu option

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio, ms-word

I am trying to make a Windows Form application using Visual Studio in which I right click on a word document, select an item 'pages count' from the right-click menu, and a form will pop up with the number of pages in that document.

Am I right to be using Visual Studio for this?

How do I call "thisDocument" or "activeDocument", and make the document the one that is selected in the menu, if the document is not actually open?

I saw that for application.ThisWorkbook, if it the application is an add-in, it will bring up the application calling it, but I am not quite sure if an add-in is part of Visual Studio?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193227.aspx

I hope this question isn't too basic -- all these things sound so similar to me, I'm having trouble sorting it all out with googling and reading questions.

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: In which application do you do the right clicking? Windows Explorer? Or do you have your list of Word Documents in your own application of sorts?

Comment: Yes, it's in Windows Explorer. The documents will be on a shared drive; I am not sure if that changes things